# how to populate values in my Qdialogbox's linedits?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qmainwindow, qdialog

In my main window, I have a `QlistWidget` named `employee_list` and the items in this `QListWidget` are like this :

```
<FIRM-1> name="Anna Ken" age="25" job="QtMaster" ,
<FIRM-2> name="Sir Ron" age="50" job="QtSlave"
```

So when I click the items in `employee_list` `QlistWidget`, a `dialogbox` shows up with 3 fields `name,age,job` like this

[image: Please click this link to open image]

but when this dialog box shows up, i want the fields `name,age,job` to be populated , like this, How can i achieve this ?

[image: Click to see example]

so far i have tried this.

```
void MainWindow::on_employee_list_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    QString test = item->text();             // getting the item text
    std::string test_s = test.toStdString();  //converting it to string from Qstring
    string name_part = "";                     //creating a variable in which name will be stored

        int name_pos = test_s.find("name=\"");
        for (int i = name_pos + 6; i < test_s.length();i++)
        {
            if (test_s[i] != '\"')
                name_part += test_s[i];
            else
                break;                         //extracting name in the item's text, after this the name_part variable value is Sir ron.  // similar code for extarcting age and job.
            
    if (test_s.find("<FIRM-1>") != std::string::npos)   //if item contains text <FIRM-1> then show this dialogue
    {
        GrpComd grpComd;   //creating instance of dialog
        grpComd.exec();    //showing it 
              
       grpComd.name_lineedit->settext(name_part);  // i tried this to populate name in name_linedit but getting error , access violation reading location
    }
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for the edit, my reputation being less than 10, i was not able to post images normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fill and then display i.e. `setText()` and after that `show()` or `exec()`:

```
if (test_s.find("<FIRM-1>") != std::string::npos)  
{
    GrpComd grpComd;
    grpComd.setName(clickedName); 
    grpComd.setJob(clickedJob); 
    grpComd.setAge(clickedAge); 
    grpComd.exec();  
}
```

or even better, if not already defined, create a constructor with those fields.

```
GrpComd::GrpComd(const QString& name,const QString& job, uint age);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't see your code for `GrpComd`, we have no way of knowing whether or not you initialized that pointer. Or even if it is a `public` member.

Regardless, you should be setting the text before you call dialog `exec()`. And the method of `QLineEdit` is `setText` not "settext" -- note the capital 'T'